# Как прятать ActionBar при прокрутке?

Tags: actionbar, android, java

Здравствуйте. Я разрабатываю мобильное приложение в *Android Studio* (в качестве тренировки) и захотелось реализовать исчезающий *ActionBar*. То бишь, у меня есть *Activity*, которая вмещает в себя *Fragment* c *ListView*.

**Задача:** при прокручивании списка (вниз, к примеру) *ActionBar* исчезал, а при прокручивании вверх - появлялся.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать или в каком направлении рыть информацию.

Comment: Я думаю, что на ListView нужно повесить onScrollListener (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) и с помощью него проверять, в какую же сторону мы крутим этот список. После этого уже показывать или скрывать ActionBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. setOnScrollListener на список
2. тут сложности, потому немного помогу, так как скролл не возвращает направление, надо написать свой, у меня такой есть ( у меня расширение скролла nostra13, тебе надо будет сделать от обычного (implements OnScrollListener)
3. ну и в конце применить его

myList.setOnScrollListener(new AdvicePauseOnScrollListener(true, true,
            likeListMyLike, new AdvicePauseOnScrollListener.IOnScrollCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void doing(int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            //
        }

```
    @Override
    public void scrollDirection(boolean direction) {
        if (direction) {
            // показываем бар
        } else {
          // скрываем
        }
    }
}
));
```

public class AdvicePauseOnScrollListener extends PauseOnScrollListener {

```
    private ListView lw;

    int mLastFirstVisibleItem;
    boolean mIsScrollingUp = true;

    private IOnScrollCallBack iOnScrollCallBack;

    public AdvicePauseOnScrollListener(boolean pauseOnScroll, boolean pauseOnFling, ListView lw, IOnScrollCallBack iOnScrollCallBack) {
        super(pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
        this.lw = lw;
        this.iOnScrollCallBack = iOnScrollCallBack;
    }

    public AdvicePauseOnScrollListener(boolean pauseOnScroll, boolean pauseOnFling) {
        super(pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
        if (view.getId() == lw.getId()) {
            final int currentFirstVisibleItem = lw.getFirstVisiblePosition();

            if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                mIsScrollingUp = false;
            } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                mIsScrollingUp = true;
            }
            mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;

            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                iOnScrollCallBack.scrollDirection(mIsScrollingUp);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        super.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
        iOnScrollCallBack.doing(firstVisibleItem, totalItemCount);
    }

    public interface IOnScrollCallBack {

        void doing(int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount);

        void scrollDirection(boolean direction);
    }

}
```

лишние методы типа doing() можно удалить..

Comment: Спасибо. Но часть вопроса осталась. Как работать с позицией ActionBar'a? К примеру, можно сделать проще, то бишь не перемещать ActionBar, а менять его прозрачность. К примеру сделать параметр Overlay у ActionBar true и тогда использовать метод setAlpha(). Ну, а если все таки рассматривать перемещение ActionBar'a, то какой использовать метод?

Comment: можно http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#hide() + анимация или как уже придумаешь